# Append list element to some txt file

Tags: python

I have a list of users and a list of txt files.
For each file that matches the user, I need to "open" the matched file and append to it the name of user after the string "ID NAME:".

My files are this:

```
j.smith@google.com-20170927.txt
a.cooper@google.com-20170925.txt
s.king@google.com-20170926.txt
...
...
```

I try this but doesn't work:

```
import os
import glob
import re

users = ['j.smith@google.com', 'a.cooper@google.com', 's.king@google.com']

'''Get user without mail ext'''
a = []
for itemc in (users):
    itemc = itemc.rpartition('@')[0]
    a.append(itemc)

'''Get all txt file'''
c = []
txt_file = []
os.chdir("C:\txt")
files = glob.glob('*.txt')
for file in files:
    txt_file.append(file)
c = []

''' Append user to txt file -NOT WORK '''
for itema in users:
for itemb in (txt_file):
    if re.search(itema, itemb):
        c.append(itemb)
        for txtfile in c:
            with open(txtfile, 'rw') as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
            for i, line in enumerate(lines):
                if line.startswith('ID NAME:'):
                    line[i] = line[i].strip() + (itema)
            f.seek(0)
            for line in lines:
                f.write(line)
```

Example of my original file:

```
A:CALFSL
VERSION:1.0
SCALE:G
B:REQUEST
C:010101010
START:20170929T000000
END:20170929T000000
STAMP:20170927T101000
MAIL:mailto:user@domain.com
CREATED:20170927T101000
DESCRIPTION:USER
CREATED:20170927T101000
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:OK
ID NAME:
V:000
Z:END
```

Comment: what is your question? what's the error/problem encountered? note: `rw` mode doesn't exist. You need `r+`. This is probably the issue

Comment: I saw this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779650/appending-a-data-in-a-specific-line-of-a-text-file-in-python.

But I don't know how to do if a have a list and not a single file or "user"

I try with 'r+' but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
s = ["j.smith@google.com-20170927.txt", "a.cooper@google.com-20170925.txt", "s.king@google.com-20170926.txt"]
for name, filename in [i.split('-') for i in s]:
    new_file_data = ["ID NAME:"+name[:name.index("@")]+"\n" if i.startswith("ID NAME:") else "MAIL:mailto:"+name + "\n" if i.startswith("MAIL") else i for i in open(name+filename)]
    final_file = open(name+filename, 'w')
    for line in new_file_data:
        final_file.write(line)
    final_file.close()
```

Comment: I get this error:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20170927.txt'

Comment: @sudosu please try again now. I have altered the code.

Comment: He search "j.smith@google.com20170927.txt" and not "j.smith@google.com-20170927.txt" I add to this to script "-" new_file_data = [i.strip('\n')+name if i.strip('\n') == "ID NAME:" else i for i in open(name+'-'+filename)]

But this script doesn't add "the username" after "ID NAME:"

Comment: @sudosu Please post an example of what your original file looks like and white the final file should be.

Comment: Thanks for you patience. Please look here what I want:
https://pastebin.com/agSbd76Z

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect! :D

Comment: @sudosu Glad to help! If this answer assisted you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!