# Appending Data In a Specific Line of Text in a File Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a file like this:

```
words
words

3245, 3445,
345634, 345678
```

I am wondering if it is possible to add data onto the 4th line of the code so the out put is this:

```
words
words

3245, 3445, 67899
345634, 345678
```

I found a similar tutorial: [appending a data in a specific line of a text file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779650/appending-a-data-in-a-specific-line-of-a-text-file-in-python) 
but the problem is I don't want to use `.startswith` because the files will all have different beginnings.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54357214/5695585) a good way to solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by doing this

```
# define a function so you can re-use it for writing to other specific lines
def writetoendofline(lines, line_no, append_txt):
    lines[line_no] = lines[line_no].replace('\n', '') + append_txt + '\n'

# open the file in read mode to read the current input to memory
with open('./text', 'r') as txtfile:
    lines = txtfile.readlines()

# in your case, write to line number 4 (remember, index is 3 for 4th line)   
writetoendofline(lines, 3, ' 67899')

# write the edited content back to the file
with open('./text', 'w') as txtfile:
    txtfile.writelines(lines)

# close the file
txtfile.close()
```

Comment: This works for me in a seperate file, but when I combine it with my own code it doesn't work. It just says `eviemcmahan
eviemcmahan

3245, 3445
345634, 345678

67899`

Comment: what does your code do? maybe you can use my answer to do that specific task and once finished, you can process the file with your code? without knowing what your other code does, i am not sure why it produces those strings `eviemcmahan`

Comment: well wouldn't the `writetoendofline` not be used in the code because it is't connected to any parts of the code