# How to append to a specific line in python without overwriting

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to append to a specific line in a file by checking its first value.

```
deposit = str(deposit)
with open('Customer Statements.txt','r+') as a:
    lines = a.readlines()

    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith(loginDetails):
            trans = ('{}/Deposit|{}'.format(dt,deposit))
    with open('Customer Statements.txt','a') as a:
        a.seek(0)
        for line in lines:
            a.write(line)
            break
```

Please help! This is my code that i tried to make this work but in vain

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779650/appending-a-data-in-a-specific-line-of-a-text-file-in-python: As it stands `trans = ('{}/Deposit|{}'.format(dt,deposit))` creates a new variable `trans` and then does nothing with it. Perhaps you wanted `lines[i] = <updated line contents>`? You also shouldn't reopen your file using `with open('Customer Statements.txt','a') as a:`, as shown in the link.

Comment: then how do i append instead of write?

Comment: You already do that at the end of your code. The first time you open the file you open it as "r+" (read _and_ write), you then read in every line of text (`a.readlines()`). At the end when you call `a.seek(0)` you're moving the cursor back to the beginning of the file and then the loop re-writes every line. Essentially, you're loading the whole file, modifying the lines you want (this is where the append happens), and then re-writing all of them again, you only need to open the file once for that.

Comment: But when i run this, it overwrites the last value in the specified line

Comment: Can anyone please help

Answer (score -1):

are you seraching for the "a", append mode?

the code:

```
with open("file", "a") as f:
    f.write("text")
```

will append the string "text" at the end of the file "file" without deleting the current content of file.

in you case you probably want something close to:

```
with open('Customer Statements.txt','a') as a:
    a.write(deposit)
```

Comment: What do you mean? I want to append to the end of a specific line

Comment: I am still a beginner but I am in desperate need for this solution

Comment: Yes I want to append but for a specific line that startswith a value that is user input